# Java - Having trouble setting JFrame to a good size

Tags: java, swing

I'm making Minesweeper as a school project. It's close to completion, but the only problem now is setting JFrame's size. I just can't figure out a way to set frames to the size I want.

The program looks almost like a Swing version of the original Minesweeper on Windows XP.

The main frame's layout is flow layout. There's a top panel for the time, mines, and reset button. The top panel's using flow layout, and the bottom panel's using grid layout for the buttons.

I set the preferred size of the frame's content pane. Getting the width is easy (The numbers of fields in a row * my button size), but the problem is getting the height right. The frame always go down to the 2nd last row of the minefield.

I also tried `pack()` but it resizes it to the preferred size of the content pane, which isn't the right size to begin with. What can I do?

Comment: Do you think you can come up with a SSCCE? This is a bit hard to see the problem otherwise, as we can only guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have the JFrame (or better its contentPane) use FlowLayout since this won't give the JFrame the best size for its components. Instead why not have it use the default BorderLayout?  Your mine cell's will probably have their `getPreferredSize()` method overridden and thus will direct the size of the enclosing containers. As always, call `pack()` on the JFrame after filling it with components and before calling `setVisible(true)` on it.

Comment: Gonna try that. Didn't know it used BorderLayout by default

Answer (score 2):

Set a preferred size for the buttons in the `GridLayout` and `pack()` the frame after adding them.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to manually set the size. You should let each component display at its preferred size and use the pack() method.

> The main frame's layout is flow layout. There's a top panel for the time, mines, and reset button

I would use a BorderLayout. Create a top panel and add it to the NORTH.

Then create a panel for the grid and add it to the CENTER. If you have problems with the buttons in the grid resizing then try creating a JPanel as a wrapper panel. Add the buttons to this panel and then add this panel to the CENTER of the frame. The panel will retain its preferred size.